# Are .success() and .error() deprecated?

Tags: angularjs, promise

I can't find any documentation on `.success()` and `.error()` methods on the **Angular** official API docs.
Not under `$q` or `$http`

Have they been deprecated ?
Where can I find some documentation ?

Comment: You should look harder: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice They have been deprecated with [v1.4](https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.6/docs/api/ng/service/$http), only until 1.3 there was a special HttpPromise type.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, sir, they are. You can find it in angularjs $q [docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q).

And [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-is-angular-http-success-error-being-deprecated), has good explanation, why they became deprecated.